# Can you create shortcut in Lions Launchpad?

Tags: macos, mac, launchpad

As it says in title. I want to add one for Eclipse, to have all in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you still have the Launchpad icon on your dock try dropping the app you want to be added to Launchpad on it.

Haven't tried it myself, but I recall reading about it somewhere.

Comment: This works, but you won't be able to get rid of it normally (the X doesn't appear like it does for other apps).